# Searching a directory, excluding a list of certain file extensions

Tags: c#, directory, streamreader, file-type

I am using the following line of code to get a list of all the files under an entered path:

```
Files = Directory.GetFiles(path, ".", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

However, what I want to do is, rather than getting all files, I want to exclude any that have certain file extensions.  I am reading the list of file extensions to ignore from a text file which has one file extension per line ("*.pdf", "*.dll", etc).  I am using the following code to load the list of file extensions to ignore from the text file:

```
  ArrayList line = new ArrayList();
  using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/TextFile.txt")))
  {
      while (!reader.EndOfStream)
      {
          line.Add(reader.ReadLine());
      }
   }
```

My question is, how do I now limit my file search to not include any files that match any of those file extensions?  I don't want to add those types of files into my `Files` string array.

Comment: Well you do have a good start, but have you tried to code anything inorder to accomplish this?

Comment: im kinda having trouble thinking of how i would leave those filetypes out of search, i tried to retrieve the filetypes in textfile in another class, however i couldent include them into file adding part. im open for ideas :F

Comment: Can you think of a static array of either allowed or not allowed file types? If yes, then you can iterate through your files and check if their extension appears in your array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot specify a list of file extensions to exclude, so you will just have to get the full list and filter them out yourself.  For instance, something like this should work:

```
List<string> fileExtensionsToIgnore = new List<String>(File.ReadAllLines("~/TextFile.txt"));
List<string> fileList = new List<string>();
foreach (string filePath in Directory.GetFiles(Path, ".", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    if (!fileExtensionsToIgnore.Contains(Path.GetExtension(filePath).ToLower())
        fileList.Add(filePath);
}
string[] files = fileList.ToArray();
```

Comment: in my original code i worked with a string array, how can i convert List<string>  type into an string array ?

Comment: You could simply call `files.ToArray()` to get a `string[]`.

Comment: hey, the code has no errors but it still returns me a whole bunch of different types of file extensions including the ones i do not want( which are inside textfile like "*.dll" what might be the problem ?

Comment: @tipi Using the code I provided, the text file will simply need to list the file extensions without the wildcard and period (e.g. "pdf" instead of "*.pdf").  Also, it assumes that all the file extensions in the file are all lowercase.  If you wanted to leave the wildcard and period before each extension in the file, then you'd need to modify the `if` statement to check if the list contains `"*." + Path.GetExtension(filePath).ToLower()`.

Comment: @tipi What do you mean by "what should I change the File.ReadAllLines, File with"?  I'm not sure what you mean.  Are you asking me what the file path passed into it should be?

Comment: nevermind what i said about File, i got confused. but even tho ive changed my extensions in textfile as "pdf" etc... it still takes them i cant understand whats wrong.List<string> fileExtensionsToIgnore = new List<String>(File.ReadAllLines((Server.MapPath("~/TextFile.txt")))); 
          
  List<string> files = new List<string>();
  foreach (string filePath in Directory.GetFiles(path, ".", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
  {
      if (!fileExtensionsToIgnore.Contains(Path.GetExtension(filePath).ToLower()))
      {

          files.Add(filePath);
      }
  }

Comment: theres a problem with the if part, because when i debug i see that it goes into the if even tho the textfile has the extension

Comment: thanks mate i made it work, it should be .dll plain thanks for your time

Comment: Oops.  I thought `Path.GetExtension` returned just the extension without the period.  I was wrong.  It returns it with the period.  So, your file will need the periods before the extensions (e.g. ".pdf").  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3):

```
Files = Directory.GetFiles(path, ".", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
.Where(fileName => !line.Contains(Path.GetExtension(fileName))
.ToList();
```

Comment: You probably don't want to call `line.ToList()` once for every `fileName` in the directory listing (unless the compiler will optimize it away to one call?), but yes this is what I was alluding to.

Comment: @lc for sure ! Well, `line` as in OP's sample, should also be a `List<string>` instead of a good old ArrayList...

Comment: Yes, I agree. And depending on how long it will be, something sorted might even be better.

Answer (score 2):

check the extension before adding to arraylist:

```
string file = reader.ReadLine();
if (!stringArrayWithExtensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(file).ToLower()))
    line.Add(file);
```

Comment: stringArrayWithExtensions is not recognised :/

Comment: @tipi I think 'stringArrayWithExtensions' is string [] sawe = {"pdf","dll', ect..}

Comment: @tipi it's just a "better name" for your "line" var.

Answer (score 1):

Reading into your question a bit, the answer is no, I don't believe there's an "easy" way to do what you want.

You'll have to read all the filenames first, and manually filter based on their extension (see [System.IO.Path.GetExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension.aspx)].